# SSL handshake failed: SSL error: tlsv1 alert protocol version

Tags: ssl, svn, openssl, version

i am using Versions for Mac and try to get access to a Repository by using the option "New Repository Bookmark". After entering the URL and my username and password it just gives me the following error:

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https: ...' OPTIONS of 'https:...': SSL handshake failed: SSL error: tlsv1 alert protocol version (https:...)
```

I am new to this, does anyone know what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that VersionsApp (the version you have installed) does not support TLS 1.0, 1.1 or 1.2 and supports SSL 3.0 only. Try upgrading your client and contact support if it does not help.

If your SVN server is VisualSVN Server, you can also try tuning the [TLS/SSL compatibility levels](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00105/).

Answer (score 0):

I have used Versions successfully for some time now. After installing it on a brand new machine and attempting to create a bookmark for a particular SVN repo, I ran into the same error. I was able to resolve the issue with the following.

- From the menu, select "Versions" -> "Preferences"
- For "Subversion Library:", select the "1.9.4" option
- Reload Versions when prompted
- Try to create the bookmark again

Answer (score 0):

There is an additional way to fix this problem in the case of integrating SVN in Eclipse.

These are the steps:

1. Go to the default Java path
2. Navigate to ***java.security*** file, located depending on your OS:

> **Linux**
> java.security file is located in linux 64 at 
> /usr/local/lib64/jvm/java/jre/lib/security/java.security

> **Windows** 
> c:\Program Files\Java\jreX.XX\lib\security 
> c:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jreX.XX\lib\security

3. Edit this java.security file
4. Search for jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms and remove TLSv1

> Original: jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, RC4, DH keySize < 768...

> Replaced to jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, DH keySize < 768...

5. Save and try it.

Regards.